# How to pass variable on href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am trying to give another variable when `href=""`

```
<a href="a.html" id="a">Hello</a>
```

Above is my code.

I want to pass value `apple` named `fruit` variable when going to `a.html`. How can I do this in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by **when going to a.html**?

Comment: You could change the href value from `a.html` to `a.html?fruit=apple` using javascript.

Comment: @Mohammad umm.. what do you mean by when going to a.html? When I click hello then it will go to a.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way that JS can communicate (easily) between URLs is by creating a parameter on your link. For example:

```
<a href="a.html?fruit=apple" id="a">Hello</a>
```

On the receiving page, fetch that parameter data. If you are wanting the data embedded into the link purely via JS, you can append to the HREF using something similar to this by using the jQuery library:

```
$("a").attr("href", '?fruit=' + 'apple');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do this on your main page:

```
<a href="a.html?fruit=apple" id="a">Hello</a>
```

And on `a.html`, add this code:

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }

    var fruit = getParameterByName('fruit');
```

```html
<a href="a.html?fruit=apple" id="a">Hello</a>
```

Comment: Thx for the great answer.

Comment: No worries @masiboo

Comment: perhaps there is another question about the alignment @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469800/how-to-align-left-navbar-react-bootstrap do u know how to do it?

Comment: No clue sorry @masiboo

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the *href* value by concatenating the existing value with the new value:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('a');
el.href += '?fruit=apple';
console.log(el.href);
```

```html
<a href="a.html" id="a">Hello</a>
```

Comment: thx for the answer. perhaps there is another question about the alignment @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469800/how-to-align-left-navbar-react-bootstrap do u know how to do it?

Comment: That's great, but do you know how to actually access that argument?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to add query parameter `fruit=apple` to anchor tag url when new page opened. So you need to use `window.open()` to open new page

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(this.href+"?fruit=apple", '_blank');
}
```

```html
<a href="a.html" id="a">Hello</a>
```

Because new tab doesn't work in snippet, check it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2ez7r43/).

Comment: thx for the answer. perhaps there is another question about the alignment @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469800/how-to-align-left-navbar-react-bootstrap do u know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Would would need a way to acceess Html parameters.
I dont believe its possible in html. There is a good load of Javascript Methods however.

For example:

```
function getUrlVars() { 
var vars = {}; 
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) { 
   vars[key] = value; 
});
return vars;
```

}

You would call this function like so

```
var fruit = getUrlVars()["fruit"];
console.log(fruit);
//Apple
```

Your URL in href would look like:

a.html?fruit=Apple

However this is hardcoded, if you wanted some nice dynamics with this prehpas use angularJS to create this with.

[Source](https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/)

Comment: thx for the answer. perhaps there is another question about the alignment @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469800/how-to-align-left-navbar-react-bootstrap do u know how to do it?