# How to align left Navbar React-Bootstrap

Tags: navbar, react-bootstrap

My Navigation code as:-

```
    const Navigation = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Dating Service</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/CreateProfile">Create Profile</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/ViewProfile">View Profile</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

It looks like this:-

[image]

The whole page is aligned center. How can make it left aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by this:-

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Later add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Also, it is possible that we can include bootstrap.min.css cdn directly at public/index.html without installing bootstrap.